# How to isolate Mac OS X installers (e.g. Mountain Lion, Mavericks)?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I've upgraded from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion before. Now, I'm going to Mavericks.

I'm tired of downloading these big installers every time I have to use them. The installers are deleted after using them as far as my experience is concerned.

Where can I find these installers after downloading them from the App Store so that I can copy them and use them in the future? Looking up over the internet did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like other apps downloaded from the Mac App Store, they are stored in `/Applications`. Indeed, the installers are deleted once the installation is complete. Simply copy the installer out of this folder and place it somewhere else such as an external drive before installing to keep it.

Comment: Just a follow-up. Is there a way to manually configure, or at least look up, the download paths of these applications without "Preferences"?

Comment: ...No. all non-system apps are stored in either /Applications or ~/Applications

Answer (score 0):

Also, there are a number of articles on the internet on how to create a bootable installer with the Mavericks operating system.  I just created one myself.

http://osxdaily.com/2013/06/12/make-boot-os-x-mavericks-usb-install-drive/